# How to get fully sent data with socket.recv()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I have faced with some problems on python. I try to read sent data with `socket.recv(1024)`, but sometime data is very long than 1024 bytes.  I tried running this code:

```
data = b''
received = s.recv(1024)
    while len(received) > 0:
        data = data + received
        received = s.recv(1024)
```

But `while` statement causes code to run indefinitely. How can I read sent packets?

Comment: That can only happen if the other end of the socket s sending continuously enough to fill the buffer - soyou are seeing what you should expect. You can always break out of the loop when data is longer than some threshold, but don't forget to retain whatever isn't used from data to add more received data to.

Comment: How about you try `while received != null or received != ''`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you might handle this (untested):

```
MINIMUM_PACKET_LENGTH = 100
data = b''
while True:
    try:
        received = s.recv(1024)
    except:
        # you might put code here to handle the exception,
        # but otherwise:
        raise
    data = data + received
    while len(data) >= MINIMUM_PACKET_LENGTH:
        # consume a packet from the data buffer, but leave unused bytes in data
        packet = data[0:MINIMUM_PACKET_LENGTH]
        data = data[MINIMUM_PACKET_LENGTH:]
        # process packet (you could maybe use 'yield packet')
        # ....
```

Answer (score 0):

After many years of writing various networking software, I decided to answer the question myself with more clarification hoping that it might be helpful for future readers.

In short the answer is - you don't. You can not read the whole packet, because there's no concept of packet in application protocol level.

A protocol is simply a way for both parties to communicate different set of messages. The "simplest" (I know of) protocol implementation would be something like this:

```c
struct Packet {
  uint32_t packet_size;
  uint8_t  packet_body[];
}
```

The important part here is that we have a static sized header that defines dynamic properties of the payload - size in our case. Using this information the reader would first read 4 bytes of data and convert it to a `uint32 n` value[1], then try reading next n bytes from the socket.

[1] - the endianness of the value should be agreed upon beforehand on the protocol level by the client and the server.